# stop NSTimer causes error

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to stop a NSTimer

```
-(void)stopTimer:(NSTimer*)timer;
{
    if(!timer) return;
    if([timer isValid])
    {

        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;

    }



}
```

sometimes it causes 'EXC Bad Access"

sometimes I got

```
 -[__NSCFType isValid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6298eb0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType isValid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6298eb0'
```

I think my codes has checked if the NSTimer is valid, if sure then executes 'invalidate'

Welcome any comment

Comment: @monsabre: Are you using some kind of threading in your app?

Comment: can you show me how you are calling your stopTimer method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are invalidating the timer anywhere else then this will occur

Make sure everywhere that the timer is released or invalidated the pointer to it is nil

you could also add a second check of

```
if ([timer isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]])
```

Comment: but I noticed NSTimer does not stop really

Comment: I mean it looks like [timer invalidate] does not really stop the NSTimer, I used the NSTimer to trigger doing something.

Comment: I hope to change to another procedure and repeat doing same thing. So I hope to stop the NSTimer and start another NSTimer

Comment: im still not understanding - if you post more code maybe i can help

Comment: Using this as a check is really a bad idea - it fixes the symptoms in some cases, but not the underlying problem. What is happening is that the timer is becoming deallocated when it becomes invalidated, and another *random* object is allocated in its place (memory recycling) and you are trying to check if that object was your original object. But what if nothing is reallocated there? This check will throw another EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: i was figuring the if (!timer) check is going above - in that case all is well

Comment: An invalid pointer still has a value, and at no point is that changed, so it passes the check-for-nil test. That is, unless he is using ZWR, which he evidently is not because his code is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are over-releasing your timer variable.

Remove the `timer = nil;` line and see what happens.

The `invalidate` documentation says:

> This method is the only way to remove a timer from an NSRunLoop
>   object. The NSRunLoop object removes and releases the timer, either
>   just before the invalidate method returns or at some later point.
>
> If it was configured with target and user info objects, the receiver
>   releases its references to those objects as well.

Comment: I did as you said, same result

Comment: Yes, I was about to add in the same comment DanZimm just made.  It looks like it's not always a timer object being passed to your `stopTimer` method.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSTimer` should be an `ivar` or a property. Retained properties are the easiest since there retains/releases are governed by the @synthesized accessor methods. Since the class now has reference to the NSTimer pointer, there is no need to pass the timer as a parameter. this could be implemented something like this. In .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

in .m:

```
@synthesize timer = _timer;
-(void)stopTimer{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
-(void)startTimer{
    [self stopTimer];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(timerTarget) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

The likely reason your method is causing a crash is that you are passing a garbage pointer to it. Either a pointer to a valid object of the wrong class or to a deallocated object whose memory has been reclaimed.

Please not that a pointer to a deallocated object will pass the `(!timer)` check, unless the pointer (in this case timer) has been set to nil.

Answer (score 0):

If at any point the timer invalidates itself (i.e. it doesn't repeat), it is removed and released from the run loop. If you do not retain it yourself, it then becomes deallocated. Calling a method on a deallocated object causes a crash.

To fix this, you can use weak references.

```
__weak NSTimer *timer;
```

or

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

This makes it so that if at any point the timer becomes deallocated, it is also set to nil.